# Integridade do funcionamento de aplicação Java executando em longo tempo

Tags: java, hibernate, desempenho

Tenho testado minha aplicação Desktop, e notei que quando deixo executando por um longo tempo noto mudanças no comportamento das ações que deveriam ser executadas.

Minha aplicação executa utilizando Hibernate, e percebo estas alterações após algumas horas que fica em execução.

O que devo fazer para realizar testes mais apurados e verificar o que pode estar causando problemas deste tipo?

Uns dos problemas que tem ocorrido é ao preencher um cadastro de venda e gravar o comum é depois de gravado no banco limpar os campos da tela como JTable, JTextField, entre outros porém hora não limpa e mantém os dados ainda na tela se eu fechar a aplicação e abrir novamente tudo funciona de forma perfeita.

Um outro problema é a realização de todo o processo e hora na registra os dados no banco.

Comment: Que comportamentos são estes? Detalhe melhor o problema para poder te ajudar.

Comment: Dê mais detalhes, assim, só com bola de cristal.

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: Uma dúvida, você faz  `commit ` das operações do banco? Fecha as conexões também?

Comment: @Techies Sim faço o commit e fecho as conexões depois de qualquer interação com o banco.

Comment: O Sistema está em produção certo? Você tem os logs dele?

Comment: @Techies Então no caso se gerasse alguma Exception tudo bem ficaria fácil descobrir a fonte dos problemas, porém não acontece.

Comment: Eu estou tendo um problema um pouco parecido, a causa é que o sistema depois de algum tempo sem uso perde a conexão com o banco, tudo que eu faço funciona porém os campos não são atualizados também.

Comment: @Techies como chegou ao consenso de que o sistema perde a conexão com o banco de dados?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33184/discussion-between-devagil-and-techies).

Comment: Está utilizando JPA como spec?

Comment: @DouglasGaldino o que seria spec?

Comment: É especificação, referente ao Java EE, Hibernate apesar de também funcionar por sí, também funciona como implementação para a especificação JPA.

Comment: Mas no caso eu uso para uma aplicação Java SE